# Mysql recursion query not working on MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have a table "knowledgemodel"
[enter image description here][1]

My Query

```
SELECT 
  title, id, @parent:=parent_id as prnt
FROM
(SELECT @parent:=3 ) a
JOIN
(SELECT * FROM knowledgemodel ORDER BY id DESC) b
where 
@WHERE=id
```

[image]

IN MYsql 
Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.6.16 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
Above Query was working fine.

But on MariaDB im getting only one record [image]

Any help ??

Comment: I'm not sure but dosn't you miss the `ON` statement after the `JOIN`?

Comment: No `ON` needed.  This is a `CROSS JOIN` where the first table is merely to initialize `@parent`.

Comment: It seems grossly inefficient to fetch all the rows, then filter by `id`.  Move the `WHERE id=@where` into the second subquery.  Then realize that you don't need that as a subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and fix the issue.

SELECT 
T2.id, T2.title,T2.parent_id as prnt

FROM (

SELECT @r AS _id,

(SELECT @r := parent_id FROM knowledgemodel WHERE id = _id) AS parent_id,

@l := @l + 1 AS lvl

FROM (

SELECT @r := ".$value['path'].", @l := 0) vars, knowledgemodel m WHERE @r <> 0)

T1 JOIN knowledgemodel T2 ON T1._id = T2.id ORDER BY T1.id asc

The LNine SELECT "$value['path']"  @r := 5 is the ID . The result is as follows: